# JOIN SELECT отсортированный

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица вида:

```
UID, UID_ZAKAZ, DATE

UID - уникальный номер каждой записи в таблице
UID_ZAKAZ - уникальный номер заказа
DATE - некая дата
```

Так вот, по функционалу, один заказ - одна строка. Но что-то пошло не так и в строке на 2 позиции больше, чем должно быть.

Решение принял следующее: сделать `JOIN SELECT` таблицы, с группировкой по `UID_ZAKAZ` и максимальной дате (т.е. последней)

И... что-то идёт не так :(

Проблема в том, что мне нужно забрать и `UID` из этой самой таблицы, а т.к. он уникален, по нему нельзя группировать.

Собсна, написал я следующее:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT UID, UID_ZAKAZ, Max(Date) AS Date
    from [MyTable]
    GROUP BY UID_ZAKAZ)
```

Но выдаёт, конечно, ошибку, мол нельзя `UID` в отбор запихнуть т.к. по нему не группируется.

Как это сделать? Не хочу создать отдельную таблицу, хочу правильно сделать

Comment: Ну так ежли у тебя две записи с равным UID_ZAKAZ и различными UID - то вот какой из этих UID ты хочешь получить на выходе, а? вот и сервер не знает... укажи, к примеру, MAX(uid) - тогда проблем не будет. А если ты хочешь получить оба - то какая нафиг группировка? Ну и версию сервера неплохо указать бы...

Comment: *хочу правильно сделать* Пока в упор непонятно, что же именно...

Comment: @Akina, я не хочу оба варианта. Я же указал, что хочу один конкретный результат для каждого УНИКАЛЬНОГО UID_ZAKAZ, где среди них максимальная дата.

Comment: Значит, `MAX(FIRST_VALUE(uid) OVER (PARTITION BY uid_zakaz ORDER BY [date] DESC))`.